Waiting of creating WinApi mutex
I need to start a child process and wait for the creation of a shared synchronization object (preferably a mutex or an event). I connect to these synchronization objects through OpenEvent or OpenMutex. This means that as long as this process is not created, the main program should be blocked. Right now, I use something like this:

bool CheckeAppMutex(const wchar_t *mutexName)
{
    HANDLE handle;

    handle = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, mutexName);
    bool result = (handle != NULL);

    if (handle != NULL)
    {
        CloseHandle(handle);
    }

    return result;
}

bool WaiteAppMutexCreation(const wchar_t *mutexName, unsigned long msec)
{
    bool result = false;
    int n = (msec / 20) != 0 ? (msec / 20) : 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (CheckeAppMutex(mutexName))
            return true;
        Sleep(20);
    }

    return result;
}

What are the issues with the current implementation, and is there a robust alternative?
Edited 08/15/2024:
The dependent application that creates this mutex can be manually start, without the parent application. The mutex that I am checking is also used to prevent the launch of a second instance of the application. So, I already have this mutex in any case. In addition to this mutex, I have an Event that is created by the parent application. With its help, I check that the dependent application (which does not necessarily run as a child; it can be manually launched) has correctly completed the necessary operations before finishing, and while this has not happened, the parent application waits. I would prefer not to complicate the code by adding another Event or using the Event for other purposes as well

One issue is if the child creates the mutex and then exits, closing the mutex, before the parent has a chance to query it. So the parent could miss it.

Quote: Two or more processes can call CreateMutex to create the same named mutex. The first process actually creates the mutex, and subsequent processes with sufficient access rights simply open a handle to the existing mutex. This enables multiple processes to get handles of the same mutex, while relieving the user of the responsibility of ensuring that the creating process is started first.

So just use CreateMutex() instead of OpenMutex() and remove the "waite" function.

@RemyLebeau If the child application starts and immediately finishes, and the parent application does not notice this, then for me, it is as if the application did not start at all. The functions I mentioned above are needed to have confirmation that the child process has initialized correctly and created the mutex.

I'm still unclear on the question.  You ask "What are the issues with the current implementation?"  Are you looking for a code review?  Is the code you've shown and described failing in some way?  You'll likely get better responses if you tell us what symptoms you've observed.

@AdrianMcCarthy Is it possible to avoid using sleep without creating new synchronization objects and without reusing old ones? I considered that while studying the documentation, I might have missed a more elegant solution for implementing waiting for the creation of a synchronization object. How justified is the use of sleep in such situations from the perspective of software architecture? How often do such sleep-based solutions occur in practice? I would like to hear the opinions of professionals in the field of WinAPI.

@MihaS:  First, SO questions aren't supposed to solicit opinions.  The best questions focus on specific problems.  Second, waiting for the creation of a synchronization object isn't a common pattern.  Waiting for it to become signaled is the common operation.  Without more detail about what you're trying to accomplish, I can't tell if you actually need to wait for creation or if you need advice on how to set up things up so that you can wait for signaling.

You may create a mutex in the first place for others to use and wait for signaling in the process as @AdrianMcCarthy said.

Why not have the parent create the mutex, create the child process, wait on the mutex and then have the child process open the mutex and signal it?
This sequence would remove the need for a loop in the parent.

A Mutex object can't be signaled like that. An Event object would have to be used instead

@SoronelHaetir
I considered this option, but it seems to me that it would complicate my code significantly. The dependent application that creates this mutex can be manually start, without the parent application. The mutex that I am checking is also used to prevent the launch of a second instance of the application. So, I already have this mutex in any case.

@SoronelHaetir In addition to this mutex, I have an Event that is created by the parent application. With its help, I check that the dependent application (which does not necessarily run as a child; it can be manually launched) has correctly completed the necessary operations before finishing, and while this has not happened, the parent application waits. I would prefer not to complicate the code by adding another Event or using the Event for other purposes as well

Then use your existing event. Have the child do its mutex work before setting the event. That way, when the event is set, you know that the mutex is ready. In other words, include "creating the mutex" as part of the "completed the necessary operations".
